# pandas dataframe function using != np.nan never follows false path

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have the following dataframe:

```
             recordhigh  recordlow
no_year                       
01-01           NaN        NaN
01-02           NaN        NaN
01-03           NaN        NaN
01-04           NaN        NaN
01-05           NaN      -15.5
01-06           NaN        NaN
01-07           NaN        NaN
01-08           NaN        NaN
01-09           NaN        NaN
01-10           NaN        NaN
01-11           NaN      -20.0
01-12           NaN        NaN
01-13           NaN        NaN
01-14           NaN        NaN
01-15           NaN        NaN
01-16           NaN        NaN
01-17           NaN        NaN
01-18           NaN        NaN
01-19           NaN        NaN
01-20           NaN        NaN
01-21           NaN        NaN
01-22           NaN        NaN
01-23           NaN        NaN
01-24           NaN        NaN
01-25           NaN        NaN
01-26           NaN        NaN
01-27           NaN        NaN
01-28           NaN        NaN
01-29           NaN        NaN
01-30           NaN        NaN
...             ...        ...
12-02           NaN        NaN
12-03           NaN        NaN
12-04           NaN        NaN
12-05           NaN        NaN
12-06           NaN        NaN
12-07          10.0        NaN
12-08          10.0        NaN
12-09          12.2        NaN
12-10          15.0        NaN
12-11          15.6        NaN
12-12          20.0        NaN
12-13          19.4        NaN
12-14          18.3        NaN
12-15          16.1        NaN
12-16          15.0        NaN
12-17           NaN        NaN
12-18           NaN        NaN
12-19           NaN        NaN
12-20           NaN        NaN
12-21           NaN        NaN
12-22           NaN        NaN
12-23          18.3        NaN
12-24          17.2        NaN
12-25          11.1        NaN
12-26          11.7        NaN
12-27           NaN        NaN
12-28           NaN        NaN
12-29           NaN        NaN
12-30           NaN        NaN
12-31           NaN        NaN
```

I want to keep the recordhigh and recordlow when they are not NaN. Ie I want a column with all the recordhigh numbers, all the recordlow number, and NaN in case both are NaN.
I have the following code for a function to apply :

```
def keep2015record(row):
    if row['recordhigh']!=np.nan:
        row['record']=row['recordhigh']
    else:
        row['record']=row['recordlow']
    return row
```

I apply it to my dataframe:

```
df2015record=df2015record.apply(keep2015record,axis='columns')
```

And i only get a dataframe that keeps recordhigh :

```
             recordhigh  recordlow  record
no_year                               
01-01           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-02           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-03           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-04           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-05           NaN      -15.5     NaN
01-06           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-07           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-08           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-09           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-10           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-11           NaN      -20.0     NaN
01-12           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-13           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-14           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-15           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-16           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-17           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-18           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-19           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-20           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-21           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-22           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-23           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-24           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-25           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-26           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-27           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-28           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-29           NaN        NaN     NaN
01-30           NaN        NaN     NaN
...             ...        ...     ...
12-02           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-03           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-04           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-05           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-06           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-07          10.0        NaN    10.0
12-08          10.0        NaN    10.0
12-09          12.2        NaN    12.2
12-10          15.0        NaN    15.0
12-11          15.6        NaN    15.6
12-12          20.0        NaN    20.0
12-13          19.4        NaN    19.4
12-14          18.3        NaN    18.3
12-15          16.1        NaN    16.1
12-16          15.0        NaN    15.0
12-17           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-18           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-19           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-20           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-21           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-22           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-23          18.3        NaN    18.3
12-24          17.2        NaN    17.2
12-25          11.1        NaN    11.1
12-26          11.7        NaN    11.7
12-27           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-28           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-29           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-30           NaN        NaN     NaN
12-31           NaN        NaN     NaN
```

What am i doing wrong please?
I have also tried if, elif, else but i get the same result.
Thank you

Comment: Keep the title focused on the specific problem -- "beginner question" and similar tags aren't necessary. And if you can, it's better to replace "doesn't work properly" with a more specific description of the problem; I'm going to try to edit towards that end.

Comment: What is your desired result? Are you trying to conditionally assign a new column to non-NAs of existing columns? Or are you trying to filter data frame?

Comment: I want a column with all the recordhigh numbers, all the recordlow number, and NaN in case both are NaN

Comment: Note: i dont have pandas.notna(obj) on my pandas version

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess you're trying to keep the records where either "recordhigh" or "recordlow" are not nan.

In that case you can simply use:

```
df_either_nonans=df[df['recordhigh'].notna() | df['recordlow'].notna() ]
print(df)
```

result:

```
     noyear recordhigh recordlow
4   01-mag        NaN     -15.5
10  01-nov        NaN       -20
30     ...        ...       ...
36  12-lug         10       NaN
37  12-ago         10       NaN
38  12-set       12.2       NaN
39  12-ott         15       NaN
40  12-nov       15.6       NaN
41  12-dic         20       NaN
42  dic-13       19.4       NaN
43  dic-14       18.3       NaN
44  dic-15       16.1       NaN
45  dic-16         15       NaN
52  dic-23       18.3       NaN
53  dic-24       17.2       NaN
54  dic-25       11.1       NaN
55  dic-26       11.7       NaN
```

if you'd like to keep only records where both are not nan, then simply substitute "|" with "&":

```
df_both_nonans=df[df['recordhigh'].notna() & df['recordlow'].notna() ]
```

Comment: That's not how I interpret the OP's goal -- as I understand it, they want to add a `record` column that contains either `recordhigh` or `recordlow`; the problem is that with their implementation it never contains the value from `recordlow`. I don't understand their goal to include deleting any rows; while they use the word "keep", I understand the actual intent to be "populate `record`" -- otherwise the existing code wouldn't make sense.

Comment: That's right Charles

Comment: Gabriele, with your code, I have a AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'notna'